# ¿Para que sirve file_get_contents('php://input')?

Tags: php

Muy buenas noches compañeros, tengo una duda técnica solamente de teoría que es para que se utiliza ***file_get_contents('php://input')*** en ***PHP***, no entiendo muy bien su funcionamiento, se habla en foros de stackoverflow en ingles que captura datos sin procesarlos, para solicitudes o ***API*** pero no tengo la noción de su funcionamiento claro.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Tenemos un primer escenario donde si hacemos esto:**<sup>1</sup>

```
λ php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo file_get_contents("datos.txt");
"Hola Mundo SO en español"
```

Nos devuelve el contenido del archivo de texto pasado como argumento.

**Tenemos un segundo escenario con `php://input`**<sup>2</sup>

Partamos de que la documentación indica y cito:

> php:// — Acceso a distintos flujos de E/S
>   PHP ofrece una serie de flujos de E/S generales que permiten acceder tanto a los flujos de entrada y salida de PHP, a la entrada estándar, a descriptores de ficheros de salida y de errores, a flujos de ficheros temporales en memoria y en disco, y a filtros para poder manipular otros recursos de ficheros según se lee desde o se escribe en ellos.

Por lo tanto si en este caso estamos hablando de obtener los datos de una fuente y entonces partimos de un ejemplo como el siguiente:

Tenemos un formulario para mandar vía `POST` 2 valores

```
<form action="procesa.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="nombre">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Recibimos los valores haciendo uso de `file_get_contents()` de este modo:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

> `php://input` es el mecanismo de solo lectura que nos ayuda a recibir y leer los valores de una fuente en específico, como en este caso vinculamos nuestro formulario a una página que lo procesa, este mismo (*el formulario*) es la fuente de datos de lectura.

Ahora lo puedes recuperar de este modo:

```
$datos = explode("&", $data);
```

Como de la acción anterior convertimos el *string* en un vector entonces accedemos por medio del índice a cada valor deseado:

```
echo $datos[0];
echo $datos[1];
```

Obteniendo este resultado:

```
name="nombre"
email="mail@hotmail.com"
```

**Aclaraciones**

- No permite o trabaja con el [enctype="multipart/form-data"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2)
- No será capaz de recibir valores de [input type file](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/input.file.html)

**Referencias**

- [`file_get_contents`<sup>1</sup>](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php)
- [`php://input`<sup>2</sup>](https://www.php.net/manual/es/wrappers.php.php)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la información pude aclarar mi duda, con este gran ejemplo.